# setInterval em javascript nao soma

Tags: javascript

Boas, eu tenho o seguinte código javascript e quando eu tento somar o `strMessage` ele não soma, mas adiciona lado a lado ao valor e assim por diante cada vez que  executa, o que estou a fazer de errado?

```js
function main() {

  var s = 0;
  //Espera um segundo
  setInterval(function() {

$.ajax({
  url: 'teste3.php',
  success: function(strMessage) {

    s += strMessage;
  },
});

document.write(s);

  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = main;
```

Comment: talvez fosse ter que fazer strMessage um number em javascript

Comment: Converta a string para inteiro.

Comment: perfeito, resultou dei um parseInt() e resultou

Comment: s += parseInt(strMessage); ??

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Comment: não há numeros decimais?

Comment: nao ,porque????

Comment: se houvesse seria mais conveniente o `parseFloat`

Comment: de qq forma não vamos deixar uma pergunta sem resposta

Comment: hmm ok, por acaso isso se calhar me irá fazer faltamais a frente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

talvez fosse ter que fazer strMessage um number em javascript

```
s += parseInt(strMessage);
```

ou com decimais:

[parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)